# Find a specific string from Online Text File?

Tags: vb.net, string

I've heard much about you guys, I'm about to finish my application but I need to finish my login system.

I've created a notepad & uploaded it to the server with the following examples:

```
Username:TestUser1
Password:TestPass1
License:28/06/2013

Username:TestUser2
Password:TestPass2
License:30/06/2013
```

I already made a login form with a Textbox1, Textbox2 & a Button.

```
Textbox1 = InputUser
Textbox2 = InputPass
Button1 = Login
```

I want that if the button is pressed it checks the username & password matches then login with a messagebox which says: "your license is valid until: " & License.
Also, I want that every username got a password, so other users can't use other's passwords.

How can I write this code in VB.net 2010?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Does it bother you that it takes 10 minutes to crack an authentication system like this? Not only that, but all your users and passwords will be visible to the public for anyone who knows the address (which is easy to find using just a packet analyzer).

If the answer is still *no*, take a look at how to use `WebRequest` and `WebResponse` to retrieve your text file: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/456dfw4f.aspx.

PS: stackoverflow is here to solve problems in your existing code, not to write the code for you.

Comment: Okay bro, what do you recommend me to use ? Also, I will be using a crypter if this changes anything..

Comment: The most basic scenario that I can think of would be to set up your HTTP server with per-user home directories. In each home directory, put a license file that contains only the user's license (not their login) details. Finally, set up basic HTTP authentication so that you need a valid username/password combination to access the license file. If done properly, you can have 1 URL pointing to a license file that returns a different file depending on the username/password used to authenticate with.

Answer (score 0):

Someone have this for you ...

Do that with [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) and its [GetResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx) method, which gives you a [WebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse.aspx) on which you can call [GetResponseStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse.getresponsestream.aspx) to get a [Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) object to pass to your [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx).